# Simple Java Json to Array

Tags: java, json

I'm stuck on something silly I'd appriciate some help with,

I'm getting this string via a stringified object in javascript:

```
{"63F67024-6FE1-D1B9-41D2-61156F11089A":0,"7cc8732e-d532-463e-9b5e-38fe14664b9e":1,"7CC40FFC-7BED-82DF-41C3-78C2BE8CD901":2,"f7344b33-860a-4934-b1f8-044b80a7b894":3,"31f65628-12b1-4363-848d-2bce07b8ac30":4,"7CF2DCA9-7BEC-8566-41A2-4898E5C110BC":5,"7D1C42ED-7BED-82FE-41D2-5045E9F0C13F":6,"D4EC2E5B-D807-2F30-41EA-6A4D9278BE81":7,"91ACF8F7-9516-F12F-41C1-BF57E6F223BE":8,"28d65730-9da0-457b-9d25-0f33628c0e5c":9,"57D44260-6D6D-E0E0-4171-71080149751C":10}
```

What's the cleanest, simplest way to convert this into an array of objects?

I've started doing something ugly by just removing the unwanted characters and doing something like this:

```
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(value.split(",")));

    for(String s : list)
        System.out.println(s);
```

But I'm sure there is a cleaner, simpler way ideally with GSON

Comment: What's your expeted array output?

Comment: `String array[]=value.split(",");` simplest way

Comment: refer this http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string looks like a simple list of key/value pairs. How about converting it to a Map

```
public static void jsonToMap(String t) throws JSONException {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

        while( keys.hasNext() ){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            String value = jObject.getString(key); 
            map.put(key, value);

        }

        System.out.println("json : "+jObject);
        System.out.println("map : "+map);
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome answer - above and beyond! Didn't know about maps, very useful.

Comment: jackson having ObjectMapper class which also doing this but it map the with the object  and key name and object field name should be same for mapping code will be

Answer (score 1):

jackson having ObjectMapper class which also doing this but it map the with the object and key name and object field name should be same for mapping code will be

import following package

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
```

call will be

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Yourclass classObj = objectMapper
                .readValue(jsonasString,Yourclass.class);
```